# is there any way to change default frame sizes of an imageView, textLabel and detailTextLabel of cell?

Tags: iphone, object

I am trying to change frame sizes of an imageView. textLabel and detailTextLabel of UITableViewCell property on inside the UITableView. I tried with change the frame size, resizing mask, resizing subviews and so on, but there is no use. Is there any way to change default frame size? and I am using UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Note: My images took their own image size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is possible with a UITableViewDelegate method:
– tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

you can set frame sizes, position, etc. Basically any layout should have effect there.
or you can subclass UITableViewCell and override layoutSubviews: method (don't forget to call [super layoutSubviews]; first)

Actually I am doing the second approach and works excelent.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the right way is to redesigned the cell.
2 possibilities:

- Programmatically in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: (see [iOS guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15))
- with a custom UITableCellView (see [iOS guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW12))

And for the cell height: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: of the delegate